# Get object after outside function call

Tags: php

How can I call functions on the object after a outside class-instance call without using static classes.

Here is my sample (It should echo "OKAY!"):

```
class class1  {
    function func1()  {
        func3();          // function outside class
    }

    function func2()  {
        echo "AY!";
    }
}

$foo = new class1();
$foo->func1();

function func3()
{
    echo "OK";
    $foo->func2();       // class instance doesn't exist any more
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class class1  {
    function func1()  {
        func3($this);          // function outside class
    }

    function func2()  {
        echo "AY!";
    }
}

$foo = new class1();
$foo->func1();

function func3($object)
{
    echo "OK";
    $object->func2();       // class instance doesn't exist any more
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instance pass as argument. follow the code

```
<?php

class class1  {
    function func1($foo)  {
        func3($foo);          // function outside class
    }

    function func2()  {
        echo "AY!";
    }
}

$foo = new class1();
$foo->func1($foo);

function func3($foo)
{
    echo "OK";
    $foo->func2();       // class instance doesn't exist any more
}
?>
```

Output:

```
OKAY!
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to change the parameter names so that it was obvious that you're not limited by using the same `$foo` in all 3 places. Also makes sense to not pass anything to `func1` as soon as `$this` is available there.